# How to Add Sub-Totals without LINQ

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I work in a place where the in-house clients all have old version of .NET so I need to get by without LINQ. I am trying to achieve something pretty simple. The list of   my class looks like this:

```
List<TestClass> list = new List<TestClass>()
             {
                 new TestClass(){ ThisName= "A", ThisNumber = 12},
                 new TestClass(){ ThisName= "B", ThisNumber = 4},
                 new TestClass(){ ThisName= "A", ThisNumber = 7},
                 new TestClass(){ ThisName= "C", ThisNumber = 14},
                 new TestClass(){ ThisName= "C", ThisNumber = 13},
                 new TestClass(){ ThisName= "B", ThisNumber = 10},
                 new TestClass(){ ThisName= "B", ThisNumber = 8},
                 new TestClass(){ ThisName= "C", ThisNumber = 16},
                 new TestClass(){ ThisName= "A", ThisNumber = 17},
                 new TestClass(){ ThisName= "B", ThisNumber = 11},
             };
             return list;
```

and the end result should look like this:

```
A   36
B   33
C   43
```

with LINQ I would simply write this code:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = source.GroupBy(x => x.ThisName).Select(g => new {Key = g.Key, Value = g.Sum( h => h.ThisNumber)}).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Value);
```

BUT, I have to achieve the same thing without LINQ.

Thank you in advance for any idea.

Comment: Just to be sure: Your client uses a .NET framework version older than 3.5?

Comment: Create a dictionary string -> int, then enumerate the collection, and add or update the value in the dictionary.

Comment: Thank for the answers. Daniel, yes they have version 2...and unfortunately it's beyond my ability to change that. willaien,

Comment: willaien, if I understand you correctly, you can have a dictionary with unique keys only. it is impossible to have more than a single key with  the same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without Linq, you can just create your dictionary upfront, and sum the quantities in a foreach:

```
Dictionary<string, int> sumDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (var item in list) {
    if (!sumDict.ContainsKey(item.ThisName)) {
        sumDict.Add(item.ThisName, 0);
    }
    sumDict[item.ThisName] += item.ThisNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just enumerate your collection and sum as you go.

[TryGetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) has been available since .Net 2.0.

```
var results = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var item in list)
{
    int total = 0;
    if (results.TryGetValue(item.ThisName, out total))
    {
        results[item.ThisName] = total + item.ThisNumber;
    }
    else
    {
        results.Add(item.ThisName, item.ThisNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much BurnsBA. That solution works perfectly fine as well!